Does all unitary transformations of a matrix manifold form a manifold?

Let $\mathcal{M} \subset \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$ be an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times r}$, is $\mathcal{MU}:= \{ MU|M \in \mathcal{M}, U\in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}, U^{\top}U = I \}$ a smooth manifold as well?

My motivation is that I want to show for some given linear operator $\mathscr{A}:S^{n\times n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, $\{ U|\mathscr{A}(UU^{\top})=b \}$ is a smooth manifold, I have shown all $X\succeq 0$ such that $\mathscr{A}(X) =b$ can be factored into $VV^{\top}$, where $V \in \mathcal{M}$, and since $NN^{\top}=VV^{\top} \implies N = VU$ for some unitary matrix $U$, if the above claim is true, then I proved the desired theorem.
I tried using some regular value things but was not very successful. I'm not sure if this is true, and how difficult it is to show.

What is $\mathscr A$?

@TedShifrin Thank you. I clarified it. I also have a post to the problem in my motivation.
